# how to recieve FormData in controller when we use XMLHttpRequest in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

my javascript code is this

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file1", file);

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", action);
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
    if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "csrf-token") {  
        ajax.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", metas[i].getAttribute("content"));
    } 
}
ajax.send(formdata);
```

and controller

```
public function planUpload(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

request bag is empty. How can I get formdata data in controller??

Comment: Did you check that data is passed in network tab in browser inspect?

Comment: // i did this
for (var value of formData.values()) {
   console.log(value); 
} it has values

Comment: If values are displayed in network tab than you will definitely get function.

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8000/architectural-plans/plan-upload/1,
Request Method:POST,
Status Code:200 OK,
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000,
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade,

Answer (score -1):

Check in Controller:

```
dd($request->all());
```

there you should see the data from your `javascript`, if there are none, check your routes or if the script ends up successfuly.

Comment: dd($request->all());  an empty array.

Comment: We do not have the needed background of your problem. So there is most likely problem in the script, try to console log the formData

Comment: there is data in formData in console

Comment: so it also can be missing Content type in the Ajax header, but I would recommend you to use jQuery for that if there is no need to use pure javascript

Comment: https://codepen.io/Xia-lj/pen/ojNKQE it is working here but not in my implementation

Answer (score -2):

You forget to set `content-type` header to `multipart/form-data`:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
```

**EDIT**: I think the problem is here:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", metas[i].getAttribute("content"));
```

It's `X-CSRF-TOKEN` not `X-CSRF-Token`

Comment: dd($request->all()); still empty.

Comment: still empy request